# Why are HFOs like R-1234yf considered okay (for now) but PFAs are under attack? Don't they both contain strong Carbon-Fluorine bonds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, environmental-chemistry

The popular (and professional) press is awash with alarms about some so-called 'forever' chemicals, the PFAs...

The older, ozone-destroying CFCs and HCFCs, as well as global-warming-inducing HFCs, and now the world-saving HFOs, all contain strong C-F bonds, just like the poly- and per- fluoroalkyls....

So why are only the latter considered problematic for possessing long-lasting CF bonds?

Am I missing something?

Comment: You should substantiate your first sentence, remove some of the snark, introduce abbreviations and explain what "the latter" actually refers to. And a yes or no question isn't a good fit for our site.

Answer (score 4):

1. [Perfluoroalkoxy alkanes (PFA's)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfluoroalkoxy_alkane) are generally liquid or solid at STP, and stay in ground water where they can be absorbed. Organism concentrate them in tissues ([bioaccumulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioaccumulation)), and the concentration is further increased up the food chain ([bioamplification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biomagnification)). The fluorocarbons used as [refrigerants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_refrigerants) (and previously as aerosol propellants) are *gaseous*, and don't hang around at Earth's surface to be swallowed; they are quickly diluted by air (where they cause other issues in the upper atmosphere).
2. Since PFA's contain bonded oxygen and/or sulfur, the molecules are more likely to have [biological activity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per-_and_polyfluoroalkyl_substances#Health_and_environmental_concerns) than the more inert halocabons. They have known health effects, as evidenced by scientific research. e.g., [a study at Harvard](https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/news/hsph-in-the-news/pfas-health-risks-underestimated/), [the IARC](https://dceg.cancer.gov/research/what-we-study/pfas), and these [articles cited by the NIH](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7906952/).

   a.  They have been implicated in hypercholesterolemia by acting as peroxisome proliferator-activated receptor (PPAR) agonists.

   b. They have been implicates in hypothyroidism by decreasing thyroid peroxidase, resulting in decreased production and activation of thyroid hormones.

   c. They have been implicated in  liver adenomas, Leydig cell tumors of the testis, and pancreatic acinar cell tumors, possibly due to increased PPAR alpha activation in the liver which increases hepatic aromatase concentration and subsequent serum estrogen levels.